# Replace column in one table with a column with the same name from another table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to replace a column in one table with a column with the same name from another table

the below query gives an error `Column item_name in SELECT * REPLACE list is ambiguous at [6:38]`

```
WITH items AS (
    SELECT 1 as item_id, "sprocket" as item_name),
orders AS (
    SELECT 123 as order_id, 1 as item_id, "ff" as item_name)

SELECT * REPLACE (items.item_name AS item_name)
FROM orders
JOIN items on orders.item_id  = items.item_id
```

when i try to resolve ambiguity by changing `(items.item_name AS item_name)`  to `(items.item_name AS orders.item_name)` it throws a different error: `Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "." at [6:44]`

```
SELECT * REPLACE (items.item_name AS orders.item_name)
    FROM orders
    JOIN items on orders.item_id  = items.item_id
```

the workaround of changing the name of the column  to be replaced from `item_name` to `item_name_1` in one of the tables works but how come it fails on standard `table.column` syntax inside `REPLACE`

```
WITH items AS (
    SELECT 1 as item_id, "sprocket" as item_name),
orders AS (
    SELECT 123 as order_id, 1 as item_id, "ff" as item_name_1)

SELECT * REPLACE (items.item_name AS item_name_1)
FROM orders
JOIN items on orders.item_id  = items.item_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
WITH items AS (
    SELECT 1 as item_id, "sprocket" as item_name),
orders AS (
    SELECT 123 as order_id, 1 as item_id, "ff" as item_name)

SELECT orders.* REPLACE (items.item_name AS item_name)
FROM orders
JOIN items on orders.item_id  = items.item_id
```

Comment: Oh, so simple, thanks!